# XML/XSD for type with extension and attribute with restriction

Tags: xml, xsd, lxml

I have the following XML possibilities:

1. `<Platform>iTunes</Platform>`
2. `<Platform IsSubscriptionPlatform="True">Netflix</Platform>`

What would be the correct XSD element for this? So far I have:

```
<xs:element name="Platform">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="IsSubscriptionPlatform" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="(True|False)?" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How would I further add the restriction of the platform value to be either "iTunes" or "Netflix". That is, where would I add:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="iTunes" />
  <xs:enumeration value="Netflix" />
</xs:restriction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your XSD modified to accept your XML as valid:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="PlatformCompany">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="iTunes" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Netflix" />
    </xs:restriction>    
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Platform">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="PlatformCompany">
          <xs:attribute name="IsSubscriptionPlatform" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="(True|False)?" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Note that your declaration of `@IsSubscriptionPlatform` allows it to be empty.  If you don't want that, remove the `?`, or use enumerations. Or, if you're free to change the XML design, go with `true` and `false` instead and simplify your declaration to this:

```
<xs:attribute name="IsSubscriptionPlatform" use="optional" type="xs:boolean"/>
```